# Unexpected end of input?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class-eval

in the following code I am running into an error which states `syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting :: or '[' or '.' (SyntaxError)` But I don't see where the issue is.

```
module Xaaron
  class ApiKey.class_eval # It does not like this....
     include Promiscuous::Publisher
     publish :xaaron_users_id, :api_key, :as => :ApiKey
  end
end
```

Am I using `class_eval` wrong?

Comment: Yes, you probably want to just delete `.class_eval` altogether.

Comment: No I do not, as I am reopening the class....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either remove the `class` keyword, and add `do` after calling [`class_eval`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Module.html#method-i-class_eval) (passing it a block):

```
module Xaaron
  ApiKey.class_eval do
     include Promiscuous::Publisher
     publish :xaaron_users_id, :api_key, :as => :ApiKey
  end
end
```

(given that `ApiKey` already exists)

OR you can remove the `class_eval` altogether:

```
module Xaaron
  class ApiKey
     include Promiscuous::Publisher
     publish :xaaron_users_id, :api_key, :as => :ApiKey
  end
end
```

This will work even if the `ApiKey` already exists... that's just the way ruby works...